# Is there a way to perform a word count of a column in Python while filtering undesired words?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, count, word-count

The idea is to count every single world in a column, but the problem is that I have words such as "and", "or", "to", "the", etc above the meaningful words. Is there a way that I can filter it?

So far I am here:

```
JobsADS = pd.read_csv (r'C:\...\monster_com-job_sample.csv')
job_description = JobsADS['job_description']
JobsADS.job_description.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

```
JobsADS.job_description.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
Out[14]: 
and                               435368
to                                239437
the                               194229
of                                176424
in                                126946
a                                 125984
with                               95454
for                                91456
is                                 60683
or                                 60657
as                                 50879
be                                 41531
are                                35433
on                                 34621
work                               33693
an                                 31349
will                               30128
by                                 29714
experience                         29031
our                                28916
all                                28459
...
mechanical/                            1
•Machines                              1
Moppet                                 1
unlinked,                              1
skills.-Proven                         1
advice.Assist                          1
DNCS,                                  1
reports.Apply                          1
partner-level                          1
CSmith@platinumhrm.comSubject:         1
plus.Requires                          1
implementationMust                     1
95123Job                               1
FULL-SERVICE                           1
calculation.Analyzing                  1
800-53).                               1
requirements.Monitors                  1
(ADR)                                  1
Smartsheets                            1
quality•Print,                         1
Monticello,                            1
workforce.Warehouse                    1
DescriptionSummary:The                 1
```

Comment: Those common words are generally called stop words, by the way. But in general, since you're using Pandas, just filter the dataframe before calling `value_counts()`?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?